# How to sort nested collection in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, nested, entity

I have entity models like this:

**Form > FormResponse > FormItem > FormItemType**

Form can have multiple FormResponses, but each FormResponse can have 1 FormItem and FormItem can have 1 FormItem Type.

**I am trying to get all forms with responses that are ordered by FormItem.ItemOrder field. So, this question is about ordering.**

Below is my attempt that actually works, but I have doubt about ToList() evaluation where I am getting FormResponses. Does this means that FormResponses will be evaluated for each form? Meaning, the query will be very slow. **Is there a way to write below statement in more efficient way?**

Tried to remove ToList() evaluation and in that case I get error that **`IOrderedEnumerable<FormResponse>`** cannot cast to **`ICollection<FormResponse>`**.

```
var forms = db.Forms
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(p => new Form 
                { 
                   Name = p.Name,
                   FormResponses = p.FormResponses.
                                    .OrderBy(i => i.FormItem.ItemOrder)
                                    .ToList(),
                   OrderNumber = p.OrderNumber
                })
              .ToList();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this query to be efficient all you need to do is remove the `AsEnumerable()` call.  Then rather than doing all of this work in LINQ to objects, it'll be done on the database side of things.

Of course, the work will still need to be done, given that you've given yourself the constraint that your final output be a list of items that has a list of items.  Given that requirement there's no way to avoid ordering all of the items in every sub collection of every item in the outer collection.

Comment: I tried removing AsEnumerable, but I get error stating that Entity or complex type MyModel.Form cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Comment: @bobetko Then construct an anonymous type in the EF query and then copy it to a `Form` in memory, afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Form can have multiple FormResponses, but each FormResponse can have 1 FormItem and FormItem can have 1 FormItem Type.

you can merge FormItem and FormItemType to FormResponse